# Repeat every first n rows m times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, repeat

Its a very simple question, i was wandering if there is simple technique without using loops if possible, it must be already answered somewhere but i cannot find it.
I have a data frame of 1014 rows, what I want to do is repeat first 6 rows n times, then repeat 6 rows after the first 6 rows n times and similarly every 6 rows

Suppose for a simple example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1,2,9,2,3,1,2,4], 
                   'Y': [6,7,8,9,0,4,6,7]})
```

Lets repeat every two row 3 times. (example first 2 rows and second 2 rows are repeated 3 times)
so what i want to get is

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1,2,1,2,1,2,9,2,9,2,9,2], 
                   'Y': [6,7,6,7,6,7,8,9,8,9,8,9]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to repeat certain rows of data, would it not be better to do so wherever it's needed in your application?

For what it's worth, the following repeats two rows of a dataframe at its second position.

You could create a loop to repeat this process every n number of rows.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1,2,9,2,3,1,2,4], 
                   'Y': [6,7,8,9,0,4,6,7]}) 

print(pandasql.sqldf("select * from df", locals()))

df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:2], df[1:3], df.iloc[2:]]).reset_index(drop=True)

print(pandasql.sqldf("select * from df", locals()))
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight ... yeah i have many data files over which this should be done and so i already have a lot of loops, so was wandering to avoid loops, but thanks for the insight again

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way by duplicating in groups:

```
# create group id
df['grp'] = df.groupby(df.index % 2).cumcount()

# duplicate group
df = (df
      .query("grp <= 1") # take first two groups
      .groupby('grp', as_index=False)
      .apply(lambda x: x.append(x)) # duplicate group
      .reset_index(drop=True)
      .drop("grp", axis=1))

print(df)

   X  Y
0  1  6
1  2  7
2  1  6
3  2  7
4  9  8
5  2  9
6  9  8
7  2  9
```